# Can you set a background image or video in Visual Studio?

Tags: image, visual-studio, video, background

Can Visual studio have a background image or video behind your code? I code nonstop while watching videos and I want to combine the activities. If not, would it be possible for me to code my own Visual Studio extension to do so?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kbuchi.ClaudiaIDE